# Размытие через функцию насыщения и матрицу коэффициентов

Tags: c#, bitmap, color

Всем Привет!

сделал программу которая импортирует картинку и переводит её в картинку-негатив. Пытаюсь её переделать (именно нужно дополнить/переделать) в программу которая размывает картинку через через функцию насыщения и матрицу коэффициентов?

Почитал вот эту статью https://habr.com/ru/post/142818/, что то прояснилось но вопросы остались...

Можете пожалуйста помочь/подсказать в каком направлении делать?

```
       const int maxRgb = 255;
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap("..\\..\\image.jpg");

        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; ++x)
            {
                Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(maxRgb - pixel.R, maxRgb - pixel.G, maxRgb - pixel.B);

                image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            }
        }

        image.Save("out.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем случае реализации добавьте ещё два вложенных цикла - получите пикселы окрестности (например, 3x3 или 5x5) и сложите их значения поканально с нужными коэффициентами. Для начала - с единичными, разделив на количество пикселов - это так называемый box-фильтр. Потом используйте коэффициенты фильтра Гаусса.

Увидев, что всё работает, но медленно (для больших апертур (размеров) ядра фильтра), приступите к применению фильтрации через свёртку, или используйте одну из многочисленных библиотек обработки изображений.

Comment: Может быть пожалуйста подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: А что именно непонятно?